# ¿Cómo sería la puntuación de esta pregunta?

Tags: puntuación

> ¿Sabes si alguien vendrá aquí por la  mañana, más allá del tipo que hizo el trámite de la solicitud en primer lugar?

¿Queda todo entre los signos de pregunta? Parecería que sí pero me quedé en duda.

Comment: La puntuación también sirve  de guía al lector.  En una pregunta, la última palabra sube de tono.  Cuando pones todo entre los signos de pregunta,  la palabra lugar sube de tono.

Answer (score 2):

Es una cuestión de estilo. Me parece que partida en dos la oración cobra mayor claridad y focaliza la pregunta central (lo que se desea saber). La otra parte es subalterna, pudiendo ir entre paréntesis, (dando contexto)

> ¿Sabes si alguien vendrá aquí por la mañana? (más allá del tipo que hizo el trámite de la solicitud en primer lugar)

Comment: gracias @fedorqui'SOstopharming', es cierto, saqué la coma porque el parentesis es en si un delimitador

Comment: puede verse incluso sin paréntesis a mi parecer